# SwiftUI Text With minimumscaleFactor Always Reducing Text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I'm running into a problem with some SwiftUI for widget code.  I want to create a Text component that scales the text down but ONLY if the text it contains won't fit.  However I'm seeing that it is down scaling the text all of the time.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 Text(verbatim: entry.records[0].value)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Thin", size: 48))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.75)
        .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 48, idealHeight: 48, maxHeight: 48, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.top, 0)
        .padding(.bottom, 12)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
```

Comment: Please be more specific: which text, in which layout, context, etc.?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer.  This is for an iOS 14 widget

Answer (score 0):

It looks like running is normal after running your code. (Figure 1, Figure 2)

If you still have questions, remove `maxWidth: .infinity,`  and take a look. (Figure 3)
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

Please let me know what the end result is.
This is my test code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world")
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Thin", size: 48))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 200, minHeight: 48, idealHeight: 48, maxHeight: 48, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.top, 0)
        .padding(.bottom, 12)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

update #1

[image: Figure 4]
You can refer to this code for alignment issues. Use HStack for layout.

```
    HStack {
        Text(verbatim: "Hello")
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Thin", size: 48))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        .frame(minWidth: 10, idealWidth: 120, maxWidth: 120, minHeight: 48, idealHeight: 48, maxHeight: 48, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.top, 0)
        .padding(.bottom, 12)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: So I tried removing the maxwidth: .infinity and still the default text size is smaller than 48.  Additionally removing the maxwidth ended up with the text not being 100% left justified.

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed information on the layout? Or you can focus on checking the `ideaWidth` and `maxWidth` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect is due to given `.frame` limitation. In you don't want text to be scaled then don't limit frame for it, eg

```
Text(verbatim: "World")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay-Thin", size: 48))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.75)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)     // << here !!
```

*Note: 48 size of font is not equivalent to 48 points on screen.*

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to use

`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

for the parent container:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
    Text(viewModel.userEmail)
        .foregroundColor(Colors.Primary.Navy.default.color)
        .font(.headingL)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.6)
        .lineLimit(1)

    Text(viewModel.phoneNumber)
        .applyStyle(.bodyLarge)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

who might think :)